# Layovers from Canada to USA

Tags: air-travel, usa, luggage, canada, layovers

I am travelling to Boston from Canada with a layover in Newark.  Do I claim my luggage in Newark or do they transfer it to the flight to Boston and then claim my luggage in Boston?  It is a 53 minute layover in Newark.

Comment: Which airport in Canada are you departing from?  If it's one of the 8 airports that have [United States border preclearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_border_preclearance) then you may not have to claim your luggage in Newark; otherwise you definitely will have to.

Comment: User is unregistered and will likely not clarify the issue, @AriBrodsky you should post a generic answer if possible, otherwise flag for closure.

Answer (score 3):

As @AriBrodsky said in his comment, if you are departing Canada from one of 8 airports that have [United States border preclearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_border_preclearance) which are staffed by US Customs and Immigration officers, your luggage may be cleared all the way to your final destination.

If you are not departing from an airport with these preclearance procedures implemented, then you will need to claim your luggage in Newark, pass through Customs and Immigration there, and then recheck your luggage to your final destination from Newark.